# Insert into multiple tables using INSERT_IDENTITY - ADO.Net

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I want to INSERT records in multiple tables with ADO.NET.

I want to INSERT a new record into a table called Professionals. It has a foreign key mapped to a different table.
tables:

[image: Tables]

Example:

```
 cmd.CommandText = "insert T_Name select (Name.T_Name,Date.T_Name,DId.Date) values (@N,GETDATE(),???)from T_Name inner join Date ON Date.DId=T_Name.DId; ";
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N", txt_Name.Text);
```

OR

...

How can I add values into these tables at one time?

Comment: complete your question first then click "post" button.

Comment: I asked questions completely

Comment: what about OR .....   ??

Comment: Any other way
just with ADO.Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After add insert sql for first table

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

then you get last inserted id. You can use second sql parameters.

Example:

```
        var dateNow = DateTime.Now;
        var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Date (Date) VALUES (@Date);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();", cnn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dateNow);
        var insertedId = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO T_Name (Name,Date,DId) VALUES (@Name,@Date,@DId);", cnn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "Test");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dateNow);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DId", insertedId);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //or ExecuteScalar() for get last insertedId
```

Comment: Can you write an example?